# Creating MX record in Google cloud DNS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, g-suite

I am trying to add `ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM` as MX record but cannot do so.
the error is `invalid data record`. Anyone know how to fix it ?

I am using Google Cloud Platform with Google Cloud DNS. For my mail I am using Google Suite. My site works fine.

[image]

Comment: How were you trying to add it? Could you provide screenshot or command line?

Comment: @EsaJokinen thanks, I have find it out. turns out I need to fill the priority too at the beginning of the mx address

Comment: Yes, the "preference" on the field means exactly that. Also, there's that `?` button that gives explanation. ;)

Answer (score 20):

You need to prefix the FQDN with the priority:

[image]

For what it's worth, it actually says this in the help button right above the field:

[image]

> A number and DNS name of a mail exchange server, indicating priority of the server. Servers with lower numbers are tried first.

Answer (score 6):

For all of those that are getting errors after adding the first one. You must **add all MX records at once** by using the **'Add-item'**. Otherwise, you will have errors.

[image: screenshot]